# Text inputs in vertically translated scrolling div react strangely to keyboard input

Tags: html, css, webkit-transform

I'm having trouble with text inputs in a vertically scrolling div that has been translated.

In a webkit browser, view this simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbguJ/3/

Scroll to the bottom of the div, click in a text box, and press a keyboard button. The div scrolls back up to the top, and the focused input is not displayed. The expect behavior is that the div should not scroll, and that the user can continue to enter text unhindered.

It's almost as if the browser is determining where the div should scroll to without taking in to account the translate.

Any possible workarounds?

In the actual application, the element in question uses translate to animate on to the screen. Replacing the translate with a CSS animation on the 'top' property severely impacts the smoothness of the animation, but solves the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: don't use `translate`. Use `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead. I could get your fiddle to work by taking off the transform and adding

```
margin-top: -200px;
```

Comment: I think the OP is already aware of this solution, but was hoping to use translate for animations.

Comment: Looks like webkit has a bug then. Until its resolved this _is_ a workaround :)

Comment: Using a CSS3 Animation on top or margin-top doesn't provide the hardware acceleration performance that translate does. Simply sticking translate3d(0,0,0) doesn't seem to help out in this situation either.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround after thinking about it in the shower this morning.

Wrap the scrolling content in a parent div, translate the parent div normally, translate the scrolling div equal and opposite to the parent div and set top or margin-top to the amount of the parent translation to correctly align the inner div. See updated example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbguJ/5/

```
#Parent {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -200px); /* animated */
}
#Child { 
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0, 200px);
    top: -200px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Silly, but it gets the job done.